# Overriding ActiveRecord class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am setting up a User model at the moment and I have a setup where a new user is emailed an activation token. When they click on the link the controller method that is called has the line

```
@user = User.find_by_activation_token! params[:activation_token]
```

Now my activation token has a 24 hour expiry associated with it and if it has expired I want the user record destroyed. This would be easy enough for me to implement in the controller but I'm trying to be a better Rails developer and a better Ruby programmer so I thought I should put this in the model (skinny controller, fat model!). I thought it would also give me better insight into class methods.

I have made several attempts at this but have been quite unsuccessful. This is my best effort so far;

```
def self.find_by_activation_token!(activation_token)
  user = self.where(activation_token: activation_token).first #I also tried User.where but to no avail
  if user && user.activation_token_expiry < Time.now
    user.destroy
    raise ActivationTokenExpired
  else
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end
  user
end
```

Do I have to change much to get this to do what I want it to do, or am I on the wrong track entirely?

Comment: Why does this not work for you?

Comment: Good point. If I call User.find_by_activation_token!(valid_token), I get a RecordNotFound exception. My self.where(activation_token: activation_token) seems faulty.

Comment: Yes. Here's some console output to demonstrate. https://gist.github.com/2924053

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got this. Your condition logic is a bit off

```
def self.find_by_activation_token!(activation_token)
  user = self.where(activation_token: activation_token).first #I also tried User.where but to no avail
  # if this user exists AND is expired
  if user && user.activation_token_expiry < Time.now
    user.destroy
    raise ActivationTokenExpired
  # otherwise (user does not exist OR is not expired)
  else
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end
  user
end
```

I think it should be more like this:

```
def self.find_by_activation_token!(activation_token)
  user = self.where(activation_token: activation_token).first #I also tried User.where but to no avail

  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless user

  if user.activation_token_expiry < Time.now
    user.destroy
    raise ActivationTokenExpired
  end

  user
end
```

Comment: Yep, that works just fine. I was so tied up thinking class methods are something more special than they are that I didn't stop to look at my code properly. I'm embarrassed but grateful. Thanks for such a rapid response.

Comment: Out of interest, is this a reasonable way to do what I'm doing? From an architectural appropriateness point of view.

Comment: @brad: Looks quite appropriate to me. Although I personally would purge expired accounts in a periodic background job.